# mysql innodb buffer pool allocation error

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have mysql running on a windows machine with 3GB usable RAM and a single core. However, when I allocate more than 1GB to innodb_buffer_pool_size, I get an error saying

> 'mysql service cannot be started' because memory could not be
>   allocated to the innodb_buffer_pool.

I want to allocate atleast 2 GB to improve my performance. Any ideas/suggestions as to how I can achieve this. All my other mysql variable values are quite small (16M - 64M).

Comment: Are you on 32-bit or 64-bit Windows?

Comment: Well, then I dare say you could achieve this by switching to a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

Very very late answer but I had the same problem and found this solution:

In 32 bit Windows w/ 4 Gb RAM, not all 4 Gb RAM is available for application space. In reality there is a [2Gb/2Gb split](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/02/23/memory-management-101.aspx?Redirected=true) between userland and kernelspace.

The solution already given (and hopefully implemented) is to use a 64 bit OS along with 64 bit version of MySQL.

[This post contains an idea](http://harrison-fisk.blogspot.co.nz/2009/02/mysql-windows-32-bit-and-3gb.html) to [extend userland memory to 3Gb](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/03/23/memory-management-demystifying-3gb.aspx?Redirected=true) via a modification to the MySQL binary.